# how do I write this correctly?

Tags: jquery

Good day.

**Code:**

```
$('.op').click(function() {
    var id=this.id;
    $('.'+id).toggle();

});
```

i get error: `{"error": "Please use POST request"}`

*Tell me please how right write?*

Comment: "how right write" -- what does that mean? Do you mean "how do I write this correctly?"

Comment: this is the same but if you want..

Comment: That error happens when you post a form on jsfiddle.net, because it doesn't run any server scripts except its simple AJAX echo scripts.

Comment: There is something happening here that is not visible just from the code you posted. The response you're getting is something you'd expect from an AJAX service call (as @Barmar pointed out). That AJAX call is **not** happening in the code you provided.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Prevent your default click by using `e.preventDefault()`:

```
$('.op').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=this.id;
    $('.'+id).toggle();

});
```

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what `.op` is:

```
$('.op').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggle();
});
```

If you insist on using `id` (which I don't know why), you must use `$('#'+id).toggle();`

**Edit**: As @[Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) explained more, you can use this:

```
$('.op').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var id=this.id;
    $('.'+id).toggle();
});
```

Comment: not id. need use toogle for class `id = this.id`

Comment: Why would you need that?

Comment: It's a reasonable thing to do. You click a button and it toggles a bunch of other elements. You link the button with the related elements by giving them a class that matches the button's ID. I suspect what's causing the error is that he's doing this with a submit button. So after it toggles things, it tries to submit the form.

Comment: Got it. But he didn't explain. He gave us a code and said how to write it correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You are asking a very strange question. POST requests have nothing to do with click events.

But ids are generally targetted with #, like so

```
$('.op').click(function() {
    var id=$(this).attr("id");
    $('#'+id).toggle();
});
```

I also took the liberty of changing the access of the id attribute.

Comment: Why did you change the class to an id? If he wants to toggle the ID, he could just do `$(this).toggle()`.

Comment: "I also took the liberty of changing the access of the id attribute." Don't. The way they had it before is the best way to access the `id` **property** of an element you have a reference to. You've introduced two totally unnecessary function calls, one of which is the wrong function (use `.prop()` not `.attr()`).